# Files have the same inode but they don't link to each other

Tags: linux, files, hard-link

I have a bash script in two places and I can't remember how I created them. they have the same inode but none of them seem to link to another. is there a hard link but should not Links count for that inode become two?

```
$ ls -l ~/bin/dropbox-backup 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bak bak 676 Aug 14 09:32 dropbox-backup

$ ls -l ~/Dropbox/linux/scripts/dropbox-backup 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 bak bak 676 Aug 14 09:32 ~/Dropbox/linux/scripts/dropbox-backup

$ stat ~/bin/dropbox-backup 
  File: `dropbox-backup'
  Size: 676         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 528738      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/     bak)   Gid: ( 1001/     bak)
Access: 2013-08-14 20:40:25.599322386 +0100
Modify: 2013-08-14 09:32:47.748546462 +0100
Change: 2013-08-14 20:40:25.591322386 +0100
 Birth: -

$ stat ~/Dropbox/linux/scripts/dropbox-backup
  File: `/home/rag/Dropbox/linux/scripts/dropbox-backup'
  Size: 676         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 528738      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/     bak)   Gid: ( 1001/     bak)
Access: 2013-08-14 20:40:25.599322386 +0100
Modify: 2013-08-14 09:32:47.748546462 +0100
Change: 2013-08-14 20:40:25.591322386 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Maybe there is a link in the path? What filesystem?

Comment: Yes, like `~/Dropbox/linux/scripts` being a symlink to `~/bin`. Run `namei -l` on both files.

Comment: @Stephane: you are correct. ~/bin is a symlink to ~/Dropbox/linux/scripts. thanks.

Comment: @Stephane I'll leave you to post the _correct_ answer and retract my nonsense :)

Comment: DravSloan, I'll leave that to @frostschutz as he pointed it out first :-)

Comment: @PeterCordes No, it is not a duplicate because the two files are in the same filesystem.

Comment: @andcoz: oops thanks, I was assuming the title was correct when looking for duplicates of [Can two files on two separate filesystems share the same inode number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/464392).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files have the same inode and are on the same filesystem. You can see that in the output of `stat`: it reports `Device: 806h/2054d  Inode: 528738` for both files. All native unix filesystems report distinct inodes for distinct files (this may not be guaranteed for some remote or foreign filesystems).

The two names for the files do “link to each other”, or more properly speaking, they *lead to the same file*. `~/bin/dropbox-backup` and `~/Dropbox/linux/scripts/dropbox-backup` are the same file. The most likely explanation is that `~/bin` is a symbolic link to `~/Dropbox/linux/scripts` or vice versa, so that you're reaching the same file through two different directory and symbolic link chains.

You can check that by comparing the canonicalizations of the two paths (i.e. the paths with all symbolic links resolved):

```
readlink -nf ~/bin/dropbox-backup ~/Dropbox/linux/scripts/dropbox-backup
```