# Can two files on two separate filesystems share the same inode number?

Tags: filesystems, inode

If I run a command like this one:

```
find / -inum 12582925
```

Is there a chance that this will list two files on separate mounted filesystems (from separate partitions) that happen to have been assigned the same number? Is the inode number unique on a single filesystem, or across all mounted filesystems?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An inode number is only unique on a single file system. One example you’ll run into quickly is the root inode on ext2/3/4 file systems, which is 2:

```
$ ls -id / /home
2 /    2 /home
```

If you run (assuming GNU `find`)

```
find / -printf "%i %p\n" | sort -n | less
```

on a system with multiple file systems you’ll see many, many duplicate inode numbers (although you need to take the output with a pinch of salt since it will also include hard links).

When you’re looking for a file by inode number, you can use `find`’s `-xdev` option to limit its search to the file system containing the start path, if you have a single start path:

```
find / -xdev -inum 12582925
```

will only find files with inode number 12582925 on the root file system. (`-xdev` also works with multiple start paths, but then its usefulness is reduced in this particular case.)

It's the combination of inode number and device number (`st_dev` and `st_ino` in the `stat` structure, `%D %i` in GNU `find`'s `-printf`) that identifies a file uniquely (on a given system). If two directory entries have the same inode and dev number, they refer to  the same file (though possibly through two different mounts of a same file system for bind mounts).

Some `find` implementations also have a `-samefile` predicate that will find files with the same device and inode number. Most `[`/`test` implementations also have a `-ef` operator to check that two files paths refer to the same file (after symlink resolution though).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the same inode number may appear at a different filesystem. If you want to specify the exact, you not only need the inode number (st_ino) but also the device where the inode resides (st_dev, itself formed by dev_major —the general class of device— and dev_minor —the specific instance—).

The couple (st_dev, st_ino) *will* identify a specific file (at least if you don't unmount the filesystem where this inode resides).

As stated on [inode(7)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man7/inode.7.html):

> **Device where inode resides**
>
> Each  inode  (as well as the associated file) resides in a filesystem that is hosted on a device.  That device is identified by the combination of its major ID (which identifies the general class of device) and minor ID (which identifies a specific instance in the general class).
>
> **Inode number**
>
> Each file in a filesystem has a unique inode number.  Inode numbers are guaranteed to be *unique only within a filesystem* (i.e., *the same inode numbers
> may  be used by different filesystems*, which is the reason that hard links may not cross filesystem boundaries).

Comment: If inodes weren't only unique to the filesystem, you couldn't safely move filesystems from one computer to another (which you **can** do, by physically moving a drive from one machine to another, or -- in VMware -- detaching a LUN from one VM and attaching it to another).